# Function works properly with relative path input but NOT with absolute path input

Tags: linux, bash, path, relative-path, absolute-path

There exists a function that is part of a software package (MRICro), and it is called 'dcm2nii.'

When a relative path is used as the output directory, the function works perfectly well.

But, when the absolute path to the exact same folder is used, the function breaks down.

Example (absolute path):

```
dcm2nii -o /net/user1/project_name/Data/2011_01_10_SVD1/Processed/3_fMRI_rest E2538S3I00*
```

Example (relative path):

```
dcm2nii -o ../Processed/3_fMRI_rest E2538S3I00*
```

Sample error message that occurs when using the absolute path for the output folder (the last line suggests that the output file can not be created):

```
Validating 52 potential DICOM images.
Found 52 DICOM images.
Converting 52/52  2
E2538S3I0001.MR.dcm->20110110_112950E2538S3I0001MRFPSD1F29OCT2010RCs003a1001.nii
GZip 20110110_112950E2538S3I0001MRFPSD1F29OCT2010RCs003a1001.nii
unable to create /net/user1/project_name/Data/2011_01_10_SVD1/Processed/3_fMRI_rest/20110110_112950E2538S3I0001MRFPSD1F29OCT2010RCs003a1001.nii.gz
```

I do not know if this problem is due to me doing something wrong in Linux/bash or due to the function actually having a mistake.

But, any input is appreciated.

On a more general level, I am looking for any foreseeable reason for why a function would be able to use a relative folder path and not an absolute one (provided that they resolve to the same location).

EDIT: pwd gives:
/net/user1/project_name/Data/2011_01_10_SVD1/3_fMRI_rest

Comment: Smells like a bug. I'd complain to the program's author.

Comment: Does this happen in a newly opened shell? If you rename the destination, create a new directory with the old name and use the original argument for the destination does it still happen?

Comment: Can you update on the 'pwd' location?  
That would help to understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

you would really have to show us the code before we can tell you what the cause of the problem is, however the behaviour you described is possible

This is an example of poor practice but consider the following

```
#!/bin/bash
....
current_dir = $(pwd)
out_dir = $1
cd ${somewhere}
..... do stuff
#no we want to come back to create the output dir
mkdir ${current_dir}/$out_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug of some kind.. I am experiencing the same issue. If I try to execute this command on data in my home folder, I get the same error.

However, if I move my data to a path that doesn't involve any expansion, i.e. ''/tmp/data'', the program executes fine.